# natbib in a different language?

Tags: biblatex, natbib, languages

I like using `natbib` for my author-year-style citations, but since I mainly write in swedish it would be nice if mine bibliography would be in swedish as well.

Can `natbib` be persuaded to speak in swedish instead of english? Or should I go for another author-year citation package instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use biblatex instead.

Comment: Their manual is horrible. It needs to be restructured. But after pulling some hair and experimenting some more I made it work like I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I've always found that the biblatex manual is very good: perhaps you might elaborate on what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a function of you bibliography style file and bibtex, not of natbib. [This FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-i18nbib) discusses multilingual bibliographies. In particular it talks about the [swebib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/swebib.html) bundle of Swedish versions of the standard bibliography styles, including plainnat.

You can also use makebst (from custom-bib package) to make natbib-compatible bst files in a "wizard" workflow. One of the questions you get asked during this process allows you to choose to make multilingual bibliographies that are babel compatible. See [this FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-custbib).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me that `natbib` the package does anything with respect to language when it comes to the bibliography entries. It seems like you should be able to make minimal modifications to the bibliography style (.bst) to produce Swedish text instead of English text.

Additionally, `natbib` works with `babel` so that should display "Bibliography" or "References" correctly (I think). Or you can just redefine `\refname` or `\bibname` to get that to display correctly in Swedish.

Comment: Using biblatex (which in itself was horrible initially) was easier than constructing custom `natbib`-styles :)

Comment: @Oscar: I was thinking it'd be a simple matter of modifying an existing one, not creating a new one. But glad it worked out with BibLaTeX. (I've never used it myself.)