# KBibTeX for other languages

Tags: bibtex, languages

I'm compiling bibliography using KBibTeX. However, when there are multiple authors, it uses the word `and`. Is there a way to tell KBibTeX to use another word for it, for example `y` (Spanish) without having to change manually the `.bib`. If there is not, is there any way to tell LaTeX/BibTeX this?

Comment: For Spanish, maybe [this document](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/info/spanish/guia-bibtex/guia-bibtex.pdf) will help?

Comment: You may also want to look at custom-bib and its included standard spanish style file. Take a look at http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=custom-bib

Comment: FWIW KBibTex is just a convenient way to view and edit your BibTex file, it doesn't have anything to do with compiling the LaTeX document (and it's not the program that chooses which word gets used between authors).

Answer (score 2):

To quote Ulrike Fischer's answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/natbib-in-a-different-language) question:

> I would use biblatex instead.

Below you'll find a complete example using `biblatex` and the spanish language. For other reasons to use `biblatex` see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/2974#2974), for details about how to switch to `biblatex` see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the biblography itself won't be compiled via kbibtex but by your Latexprogramm (kile, I guess?) it doesn't matter for your finished Document. If you'll compile on,e there wil be "und" or "y", depending on the language of your document (via \usepackage[spanish]{babel}, I think)

Comment: I'm not so sure of this, I'm already using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` and it still says and.

Comment: Kile is just an editor, it doesn't actually compile the LaTeX file.