# How to change the "and" in the reference/bibliography into when using natbib?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am writing something that needs to refer to both Chinese and English papers. 
I am using `natbib`  to format my bibliographies and I encountered a problem with the presentation of my reference when there are more than one author.

The following is one of my BibTeX entries.

```
@article{马双2012,
  title={最低工资对中国就业和工资水平的影响},
  author={马双 and 张劫 and 朱喜},
  journal={经济研究},
  volume={5},
  pages={132--146},
  year={2012}
}
```

When I cite this article using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside, cap]{ctexart}
\usepackage[colon, longnamesfirst, sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citet{马双2012}
\renewcommand\refname{参考文献}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibli}
\end{document}
```

I got

> 马双 and 张劫 and 朱喜(2012)

in the main text and

> 马双 and 张劫 and 朱喜. 最低工资对中国就业和工资水平的影响. 经济研究, 5:132-146, 2012.

in the reference section.

How can I replace the "and" in all the arguments with the corresponding Chinese character so that it would not look so odd?

Comment: The '`natbib` with different  languages' business comes up quite a bit: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18042/replacing-and-by-og-and-inby-i-in-references-and-bibliograpy-using-natbi or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4259/natbib-in-a-different-language.

Comment: I'm surprised that there would be *two* "and" conjunctions in both the citation callout and in the entry itself; the "standard" behavior of the `plainnat` bibliography style is to use `, ` for all but the final conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do the following:

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, named (say) `myplainnat.bst`. (Don't edit a file from the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open `myplainnat.bst` in a text editor. (The editor you use to edit your .tex files will do fine.)
- Find the three instances of `" and "` -- in my copy of the file, they're on lines 232, 325, and 1111 -- and replace the `and` string with the appropriate Chinese character(s). Note the spaces before the "and" substring.
- Likewise, you will probably want to replace the four instances of `" et~al."` (most likely on lines 231, 324, 1106, and 1110)  with the appropriate Chinese characters.
- Save the file `myplainnat` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in some directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution as needed.
- Start using the new bibliography style by issuing the command `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}`. Be sure to rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.