# Natbib (apalike) Changing "and" into symbol "&"

Tags: natbib, apa-style

I am using natbib for APA style in my bibliography, but i want to change

> A and B. (2018). Abc.

into

> A & B. (2018). Abc.

I know I have to copy apalike.bst into my working directory and edit it. But I don't know which part that I have to edit. Please help.

Note:
There is this similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203095/how-to-change-the-and-in-the-reference-bibliography-into-when-using-natbib) but it seems I can't find it in apalike.bst

Comment: If you really need actual APA style, why don't you use the `apacite` package with the `[natbibapa]` option and the `apacite` bibliography style. This implements a pretty good APA 6 style.

Comment: I can't because of the requirement. Actually I want to use apacite too, but unfortunately apacite is not in the list of allowed package, and the only possible package is natbib

Comment: If `apacite` is not allowed, are you sure you're allowed to use a non-standard `.bst` file?

Comment: Hmm I don't know that yet, but I guess it is still okay in my case since I use it for localization purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two functions that need to be changed in your copy of  `apalike.bst`, (I strongly recommend giving it a new name, like `apalike-ampersand.bst`) one for the label names (i.e., in text citations)  `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}` and one for the reference list names, `FUNCTION {format.names}`.

In the function `{format.lab.names}` change the line:

```
{ " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

to

```
{ " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

In the function `{format.names}` change the line:

```
{ " and " * t * }
```

to

```
{ " \& " * t * }
```

This should do what you want.